# Network.getAllCookies returns empty array on specific pages with PuPHPeteer

Tags: puppeteer, puphpeteer

I'm using this library https://packagist.org/packages/nesk/puphpeteer to get cookies from specific sites.

I've run some tests, and in some cases, I actually get some cookies, but I have no clue why for https://lanzadera.es/ I'm getting no cookies?

If I check my chrome browser, I can see the following cookies being dropped even before the cookie message is accepted:

- _ga
- _gid
- _uetsid
- _uetvid

However, I get none of them when running the below:

```
$this->puppeteer = new Puppeteer();
$this->browser = $this->puppeteer->launch(['args' => ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']]);
$this->page = $this->browser->newPage();
$this->page->goto($href, ['waitUntil' => 'networkidle2']);
$this->page->_client->send('Network.getAllCookies');
```

Environment:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Node version: v16.2.0
- PHP version: 8.0.19